# How to convert a notebook to an association and back?

Tags: notebooks, associations, cells

I have a notebook that serves as a nice readable document but is it a database of sorts, I'd like to transform this into an association so I can manipulate and export it as a dataset. Here is a sample of my notebook:

[image]

The goal is exporting the structure with a function `NotebookToDataset[nb]` that would return something like this:

```
{ <|"Author" -> "Salvador Dali", "Category" -> "Art", 
        "Quotes" ->{
            <|"Text" -> "I don't do drugs. I am drugs.", 
                     "Tags" -> {"drugs", "sarcasm"}, 
                     "Citation" -> "BrainyQuote.com. Xplore Inc, 2015. 10 March 2015.", 
                     "URL" -> "http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/s/salvadorda154013.html"|>,
            <|"Text" -> 
                      "Each morning when I awake, I experience again a supreme \
                pleasure - that of being Salvador Dali.", 
                     "Tags" -> {"funny", "inspiring"}|>
            (* more and more quotes...*)
            },
                 "BiographicalDetails" -> <|"Author Profession" -> "Artist",
                   "Nationality" "Spanish", "Born" -> "May 11, 1904", 
                   "Died" -> "January 23, 1989"|>|> 
            (* more and more authors...*)
    }
```

Note: multiple authors may be in multiple categories, for instance, quotes from Spinoza appear multiple subsections Philosophy-Epistimology, Philosophy-Ethics, Mathematics-logic, etc...

Thanks!

Comment: One obvious suggestion is to introduce unique Ids of some sort, and then store quotes in one Dataset, and the rest in the other, and refer to quotes by Id. This seems to be the only way to avoid duplicating quotes in all sub-sections. This is a general problem with hierarchical databases - you may get away with fewer data sets, than if you would use relational tables, but often for the price of data denormalization. Where to put the line here depends on the application. If your data set is generated and then is read-only, you may as well decide to denormilize the data and duplicate the quotes

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I think data duplication is only relevant with BiographicalDetails as Author and Category would uniquely identify a set of quotes, so denormalization with regards to that data is reasonable. Although, I'd consider building a secondary table which those are details are drawn from with the Author as the unique ID for it. Maybe have a structure `<| “CollectedQuotes” -> …, “AuthorDetails” -> …|>`.

Comment: @rcollyer I'd agree with this. The problem of denormalization is more important either when this leads to excessive memory usage (less important issue), or when the database is writeable and the data may become corrupted if it exists in several places and goes out of sync. For read-only databases this is much less critical.